# dynamic parameter based on character of amplitude wav file matlab

Tags: matlab, audio, dynamic, parameters, noise

i have implemented noise gate to make noise(that's not include speech) in speech wav file to become silence, but there are five parameters(sended by main program) that i must fill the parameters by my self. i have question, how can my program give suggest parameters every i input the speech wav file with different character of noise?
what i'm thinking: can i use the average of speech wav file amplitudes to get suggest parameters?

```
function n = noisegate( x, Fs, AT, RT, holdtime, ltrhold, utrhold)
% ------- Parameter Input ---------
% x - Input file
% Fs - sample frequency
% AT - Attack time 
% RT - Release time 
% ltrhold - lower threshold
% utrhold - upper threshold

att = round(AT*Fs); %calculate attack time in samples
rel = round(RT*Fs); %calculate release time in samples
ht = round(holdtime*Fs); %calculate hold time in samples
g = zeros(size(x)); %allocate an array for gain
%initialize low and high threshold counters
ltcnt = 0;
utcnt = 0;
%Calculate RMS Peak
%time average for peak measurement
tav = 0.2;
TAV =1 - exp(-2.2/(Fs*tav));
xrms(1) = 0;
for n = 2 : length(x)
 xrms(n) = (1-TAV)*xrms(n-1) + TAV*x(n)^2;
 if (xrms(n) <= ltrhold || (xrms(n) < utrhold && ltcnt > 0))
 ltcnt = ltcnt + 1;
 utcnt = 0;
 if (ltcnt > ht), %hold time of low threshold exceeded
 if(ltcnt > (ht + rel)) %hold and release time exceeded
 %set gain to zero to completely fade out the sound
 g(n) = 0;
 else
 %fade out the sound here
 g(n) = 1 - (ltcnt - ht)/rel;
 end
 elseif (ltcnt < ht & (ltcnt == n))
 g(n) = 0;
 else
 g(n) = 1;
 end
 elseif (xrms(n) > utrhold || (xrms(n) > ltrhold && utcnt > 0))
 ltcnt = 0;
 utcnt = utcnt + 1;
 if(utcnt > ht)
 %maximum attack and hold time exceeded
 if(utcnt > (ht + att))
 %set gain to 1
 g(n) = 1;
 else
 %applay gain smoothening
 g(n) = (utcnt - ht)/att;
 end
 else
 g(n) = 0;
 end
 end
end
n = x.*g;

end
```

Comment: The average power of the wav file would give you the power of signal plus noise. To set the threshold you would need to know a piece of the wav file that contains noise alone. That way you could set the threshold in between. Or compute averawe power of signal plus noise and assume that noise will always be, say, at least 20 dB below

Comment: how about dynamic range and crest factor value, can i describe the relation of noise and speech with those value?
could you please explain in detail sir?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean

Comment: dynamic range value will show range between loudness and softness sound that mean range peak amplitude and noise floor, and crest factor will show range between peak amplitude and rms.
do you know sir?

Comment: Yes, I know what those parameters are, but I don't see what their relation with your original question

Comment: i was thinking that average of amplitude will give me recommended parameter but it was too difficult to implement for me. but now i'm thinking of those value. my samples have constant noise